# iPhone takes a long time to turn on while charging

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, charge

When my iPhone 5s dies, it usually turns on after 5-7 minutes of charging. Now, it sometimes takes 45 mins to over an hour to turn on while it's plugged in.

It also dies very easily. It can be at 100% battery, then within 10 minutes it's at 60%. Sometimes my phone even turns off at 100 or 50%.

Can somebody explain why this happens or what I should do? Is my battery broken?

Comment: Nobody will be able to tell you exactly what's going on. There needs to be diagnostic tools attached to your iPhone to determine what's happening. If your iPhone is under warranty, the best thing is to take it to Apple. If the battery is going bad, which is possibility, they can fix it.

Comment: It depends on the circumstance, i.e. charging *may* be slower when connected to a dock. Also, charging via computer may have different outputs.

Answer (score 1):

This makes great sense if your battery is aging in the normal way for a lithium cell. The automatic turn on happens when the voltage level from the battery raises above a set limit and when the battery is new, it won't discharge as deeply or take as long to rebound when you re-apply charging current.

A simple battery exchange would remedy the situation if you care to remedy this. Just knowing it's normal and expected might let you decide to just be more patient and not drain the battery past 15% so you don't have to wait when you plug it in.

The shutting off is another sign of aging - that won't get better and you can't wait that out - so replace the battery or have the phone serviced if you need that part of the operation more stable.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a battery replacement or bring it to Apple